Using a list (range) of column criteria (not single cells) in FILTER formula




A
B
C
D
E
F







Revenue

ColCrit1
ColCrit2


2
Brand A
P1
500

Brand A
P1


3
Brand A
P2
100

Brand B
P3


4
Brand A
P2
800

Brand D



5
Brand B
P1
90





6
Brand C
P4
45





7
Brand C
P2
600

Result
500


8
Brand D
P1
900


90


9
Brand D
P1
125


900


10
Brand D
P3
70


125


11
Brand D
P3
842


70


12
Brand E
P4
300


842




I want to filter the list based on multiple column criteria. 
The column criteria can be entered by the user in Range E2:E4 and Range F2:F4.
So far I have been only able to create a filter formula on single cell entries:
F7 = FILTER(C2:C12,IF(E2="",1,(A2:A12=E2))*IF(F2="",1,(B2:B12=F2)))

Do you know if there is a formula to apply the criteria as a range? 
Something like this:
F7 = FILTER(C2:C12,IF(E2:E4="",1,(A2:A12=E2:E4))*IF(F2:F4="",1,(B2:B12=F2:F4)))


Here is one way of doing this:


• Formula used in cell E6
=LET(
     α, COUNTIF(E2:E4,A2:A12),
     δ, COUNTIF(F2:F4,B2:B12),
     FILTER(C2:C12,IFS(SUM(α)=0,δ,SUM(δ)=0,α,1,α*δ),""))


